# Mathematical Logic Shoenfield chapter 1 question 5

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm working through Mathematical Logic by Joseph Shoenfield. I have finished reading chapter 1 and I'm stuck on exercise 5. The question reads

Let $T$ be a thoery with no non-logical symbols and no non logical axioms a) Show that $\neg \neg(x=x) \vee \neg(x=x)$ is a theorem of $T$ non provable without propositional axioms. [hint: let $f$ be a mapping from the set of formulas to the set of truth values such that $f(A) = \textbf{T}$ for $A$ an atomic formula; $f(\neg A) = \textbf{F}$; $f(A \vee B) = f(B)$; $f(\exists xA) = \textbf{T}$. Show that if $A$ is provable without propositional axioms then $f(A) = \textbf{T}$

My intuition tells me to use induction on the length of $A$ starting with $A$ being an atomic formula and building up from there. I ran into trouble though because what if you had a proof of a formula that looked like $\neg C \exists xD A$ where C, D and A are formulas. How would you apply f to that? I believe this satisfies Shoenfields definition of a proof on page 5. I'm really unfamiliar with how proofs in logic go and all of my attempts seemed to trivialize the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's a link to a pdf of the book
https://kupdf.com/download/joseph-r-shoenfield-1967-mathematical-logic_58df8baadc0d6036298970da_pdf

Comment: What is  $¬C∃xDA$ ? It cannot be a formula.

Comment: I was very confused as to the definition of a proof. That was supposed to be a proof of the theorem A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is by induction on the lenght of the proof, considering that we have to exclude *propositional* axioms.

1st step) we have to check that all axioms (except for the propositional ones) are **T** with the proposed interpretation.

For $x=x$, it' Ok, and also for the other *identity* axioms, because they are made of *atoms* and $f(A)=$ **T** for $A$ atomic.

For the *substitution* axioms, we are Ok, because $f(\exists x A)=$ **T**, irrespective of the truth-value of $A$.

2nd step) we have to check that the inference rules are *sound*, i.e. they produce true conclusions from true premises :

> **Expansion Rule**. Infer $B \lor A$ from $A$.

If $f(A)=$ **T**, then $f(B \lor A)=f(A)=$ **T**.

> **Contraction Rule**. Infer $A$ from $A \lor A$. Similar.
>
> **Associative Rule**. Infer $(A \lor B) \lor C$ from $(A \lor (B \lor C)$. Similar.
>
> **Cut Rule**. Infer $B \lor C$ from $A \lor B$ and $\lnot A \lor C$.

We have $f(A \lor B)=f(B)=$ **T** and $f(\lnot A \lor C)=f(C)=$ **T**; thus $f(B \lor C)=f(C)=$ **T**.

> **$\exists$-Introduction Rule.** If $x$ is not free in $B$, infer $\exists x A \to B$ from $A \to B$.

We have that $A \to B$ is $\lnot A \lor B$. Thus, $f(A \to B)=f(B)=$ **T**. And so, $f(\lnot \exists x A \lor B)=f(B)=$ **T**.

This conclude the proof that if a formula $\varphi$ is provable without propositional axioms, then $f(\varphi)=$ **T**.

But $f(¬¬(x=x) \lor ¬(x=x))=f(¬(x=x))=$ **F**, and thus it is not derivable with the said limitation.

Comment: Thank you! I was very confused on what to do